# Making a MOSFET-based constant 14 VDC input to constant 11 VDC (8-20 A) output voltage regulator circuit

Tags: voltage-regulator, high-current, high-power

I have a constant 14 VDC source and I want to get a constant regulated output of 11 VDC regardless of the load current, knowing that the load is varing from 8 to 20 A with low frequency. What is the suggested circuit?

Currently I have an RJP30E2DPK IGBT and IRL3713 and IRFZ44 N-MOSFETs. Can I use them in the circuit?

Comment: Welcome! (14-11 V)*20 A = 66 W of dissipation for a linear converter. Can any of your devices dissipate that much? Sounds to me like you need a DC-DC converter. Your IRL3713 is certainly capable of switching that, but a 260 A device will be challenging to switch. Your IRFZ44 would be the better choice here.

Comment: A linear regulator would bring the lowest ripple and fastest transient response, but also the highest loss and heat. Thermal design for a loss of 60W could be a real challenge. A switching regulator, a synchronous buck to be more specific, seems the best option. 3713 appears to be a good fit for both switches. Designing the inductor for 20A DC current and presumably 5A ripple current can be a bit of a challenge, though.

Comment: Please state, in the question, the limit guaranteed on input voltage and required on output. Do input and output need to share terminals, especially GND? An IGBT won't be your best bet in a low voltage switching application due to "high" saturation voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What is the suggested circuit?*

A switching buck regulator **like** the [LT3741](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/37411fg.pdf): -

[image]

It's a bit close to the input supply limit you specified so try looking for a device with an input range from 13 volts to 15 volts using the [Analog Device's web-page](https://www.analog.com/en/product-category/external-power-switch-buck-controllers.html): -

[image]

The LT3741 was found using 13 to 15 volts on the input selection and 11 volts and 20 amps on the output selection boxes so, it might work. But, as with all these things, you should spend maybe a couple of hours investigating. I spent 5 minutes and there may be better devices.

> *Currently I have an RJP30E2DPK IGBT and IRL3713 and IRFZ44 N-MOSFETs.
> Can I use them in the circuit?*

Not the IGBT and probably not the IRFZ44 but, the IRL3713 might be in with a shot.